# Understanding the netstat command output

Tags: windows, networking, ip, netstat

I used netstat command recently, and the output is below.

```
netstat  -a    

proto  local address          foreign address       state

tcp    127.0.0.1:1107         avinash-pc:0          listening
tcp    0.0.0.0:134            avinash-pc:0          listening
tcp    226.178.166.149:1104   a60-274-182-61:https  close_wait
udp    0.0.0.0:566            *.*                   
udp    [::]:566               *.*
```

1. When I did `netstat -n`, there was no 0.0.0.0:134 in the output... why?
2. What is meant by the first and second entries(local and foreign address are both on my computer)

   - i.e. why is my computer connecting to itself?
3. What is meant by *.* of 3rd entry and [::] of 4th entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from `netstat -h`:

```
-a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
```

As in both current connections and listening ports (half open).

```
-n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
```

As in, do not resolve addresses to host names.

Your computer can and regularly does connect to itself, usually for IPC or administrative tasks.

`*.*` = All IPv4 addresses (it's listening, so accept connections from any IPv4)
`[::]` = All IPv6 addresses (same reason as the last).

Comment: ...thanks but ...1. i think u didn't understand my first question...i know that -n gives numerical output...what i am saying is that when i used netstat -n entries of second form were displayed as ip addresses but the entry row corresponding 0.0.0.0:134 was not there...i.e. in tcp protocol first column contained just 127.0.0.1:1107 and 226.178.166.149:1104..... 2.  also i read that ports above 1024 are used only for connections with remote computers  ...but in first row my computer connects to itself using a port above 1024

Comment: 1. `-a` switch adds "listening" connections, which the "0.0.0.0:124" is, it's not "established". When running `netstat` without `-a` those "listening" entries will not be displayed. 2. What you read was wrong. Ports under 1024 are reserved for privileged communication (leaving 1024 and up for privileged or non-privileged); has nothing to do with remote vs local communication.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat  -a` vs `netstat  -n`

The `-a` options shows listening connections on your system.  The `-n` option disables name resolution.  You can combine the two options like `netstat -a -n`.  Then you would disable name resolution, and see ports your system is listening on.

> What is meant by the first and second entries

The important piece is the last column, which states listening.  Your computer is accepting incoming connections on tcp/1107 and tcp/134.

> What is meant by . of 3rd entry and [::] of 4th entry?

Again it is just ports open for listening, but UDP is displayed differently because it isn't connection based.